# How to select one result from same multiple database results

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating an inbox page where i echoed out the rows of the user from the inbox database but a user appears multiple times as appeared on the database table if you know what I mean, here is an image of what I mean:
[image]

So the name kanayo the great appears as much times it appeared in the table. I want the name to appear just once so that when clicked on it will display the message body.

Here is my code:

```
    $mymsg = mysql_query("SELECT msg_from, msg_to FROM message WHERE msg_from='$my_id' OR msg_to='$my_id' ORDER BY msg_id DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page");
while($run_msg = mysql_fetch_array($mymsg)){
    $msg_from = $run_msg['msg_from'];
    $msg_to = $run_msg['msg_to'];
    if($msg_from == $my_id){
        $users = $msg_to;
    } else {
        $users = $msg_from;
    }
    $firsts = getuser($users, 'first');
    $nicks = getuser($users, 'nick');
    $lasts = getuser($users, 'last');

echo "<div align='left'><a href='message.php?user=$users' style='text-decoration:none;><<b><font color='blue'>$firsts $nicks $lasts</font</b></a></div><br>";
    }
```

I have my functions and db connection in external files which I included.

[image]

This is an image also of my table, I don't know if its the right table structure for an inbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way would be to move your condition (checking if equal to my_id into the mysql query, and let the resulting variable be "users"). Then and the end of the query, you can add;

```
GROUP BY users
```

Which will make sure you only pull back distinct "users"

You can incorporate a condition into mysql using the IF element, i.e.

```
SELECt IF(msg_from = '$my_id', msg_to, msg_from) AS users
```

Comment: thanks matthew, yours also worked though i prefer suibber's method, its easier

Comment: No problem.Be wary of the second method - since you are grouping before applying your conditions - this could lead to a loss of data (grouping away certain data that would meet the condition) so I recommend you test it thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

use group by maybe help you

```js
$mymsg = mysql_query("SELECT msg_from, msg_to FROM message WHERE msg_from='$my_id' OR msg_to='$my_id' GROUP BY msg_from ORDER BY msg_id DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page");
```